# When i use http verify is ok, but https not allowed

Tags: nginx, https, unicorn

When I use `rack-oauth2` authorisation, HTTP is allowed, but HTTPS `token.to_mac_token.verify!(request)` is getting an  `"Signature Invalid"`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When make signature Server and Client is different port, This worry is my Server config...